# Are read operations on Java containers thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

Taking an example :

```
class Test {

    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Test() {
      myList.add(1);
      myList.add(2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       
        Test obj = new Test();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(()->{ System.out.println(obj.myList.get(0)); });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{ System.out.println(obj.myList.get(1)); });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Above, we are reading the values of an ArrayList from 2 threads. I have seen lot of code where read operations on constant lists (the lists are initialized and never altered after that) have been considered thread-safe. However, theoretically, even calling `get()` on an ArrayList can cause a change in state of the list (depending on the implementation), and so, not be thread-safe.

For example, we can have an ArrayList implementation that keeps track of the number of times `get()` is called using a non-atomic integer, which would make the get operation non thread-safe.

```
    // Just an example
    void get(int n) {
       get_counter++;
       return array[n];
    }
```

Question : Is there any Java documentation that will support the claim that read operations on Java collections is thread-safe?

Comment: Answer: No.  Because read operations on collections (in general) are NOT thread-safe.

Comment: I think this is only safe if the `Collection` is immutable. Like, `List<Integer> myList = List.of(1,2);` -- your's isn't.

Comment: Not inherently, unless otherwise specified in the object's JavaDoc.  A framework will sometimes offer thread-safe alternatives.  There aren't many.

Answer (score 1):

> Question : Is there any Java documentation that will support the claim that read operations on Java collections is thread-safe?

Answer: No.  Because read operations on collections (i.e. classes that implement `Collection`) are in general are NOT thread-safe.

Read operations may be thread safe for some collection classes or for some use-cases.  But the general claim is not supported by any (official) definitive Java documentation.

The only thing that the `Collection` interface [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) says about thread-safety is this:

> "*It is up to each collection to determine its own synchronization policy. In the absence of a stronger guarantee by the implementation, undefined behavior may result from the invocation of any method on a collection that is being mutated by another thread; this includes direct invocations, passing the collection to a method that might perform invocations, and using an existing iterator to examine the collection.*"

This basically says that reading while writing can be expected to be non-thread-safe ... unless stated otherwise in an implementation class.  That invalidates the general claim.

Your first example will be thread-safe because `ArrayList::get` doesn't mutate the list.  (We can reason this from the `ArrayList` source code using the Java Memory Model rules but I won't bore you ...)

Your second example is clearly not thread-safe. The proposed `get` operation is mutating the collection object and that falls foul of the quoted text above.  (We can also reason this using the JMM rules if we have the complete source code.)

Note that your example illustrates the claim is false in general.

But it also illustrates another point: a classic Java interface is merely a contract.  There is nothing in the Java language or its spec that prevents a class that implements an interface from *not honoring aspects of the contract*.  That applies to thread-safety as well as other things.

Hypothetically: even if collection read operations *were* specified in one of the collection interfaces meet the thread-safety claim, a collection implementation class *could* simply ignore that.